# Determine SVG Text Height in Python Flask

Tags: python, flask, svg, svg-foreign-object

I want to determine the height of the svg generated text of my flask app

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%">
    <foreignObject class="node" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%">
        <body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <style>
              // some stylings like setting font size, font family etc.
            </style>
            <div class="text">{query.replace("&", "&amp;")}</div>
        </body>
    </foreignObject>
</svg>
```

I take some parameters in the url and style the text accordingly using them like setting font to custom google fonts etc. I want to get the accurate height of the text as it is being used somewhere where pixels height is needed.

Comment: I guess you could parse the font file in whatever format it is and calculate it.

Comment: Then how do I calculate it ? I tried using cairo but it only have limited styling and font families, font weights and so doesn't work in my case

Comment: from base64 import b64encode
from requests import get

import re

def get_font_from_url(url):
    font_faces = get(f"https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family={url}&display=swap").text
    font_locations = re.findall(r"https://[^\)]+", font_faces)

    for location in font_locations:
        res = get(location)
        blob = res.content
        data_url = 'data:' + res.headers['Content-Type'] + ';base64,' + b64encode(blob).decode('utf-8')
        font_faces = font_faces.replace(location, data_url)
    
    return font_faces

Comment: I'd probably try something like harfbuzz, I believe it has a python wrapper.